# unbind and then bind the onclick function(with dynamic param) to the anchor tag in repeater in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to unbind the function(which is with parameters
        <%#Eval('')%>) and after thta on button click bind that function in jquery or javascript

```
      <ItemTemplate>
           <tr>
              <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                                                                                                  <%#Eval("Comments")%>&nbsp;
               </td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                  <a id="hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID" onclick="FillVoyageCompanyData(<%#Eval("VoyageAssosiatedCompanyID") %>);">          Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
```

Here i want to unbind "FillVoyageCompanyData" function. 
i am doind it by

```
 $("#hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID").unbind("click");
```

and then

```
 $("#hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID").bind("click", FillVoyageCompanyData);
```

but it is not working. it does not unbind the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unbind` only works for event handlers attached via jQuery

Replace:

```
<a id="hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID"
   onclick="FillVoyageCompanyData(<%#Eval("VoyageAssosiatedCompanyID") %>);">
```

With

```
<a class="hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID"
   data-vacid="<%#Eval("VoyageAssosiatedCompanyID") %>">
```

And then attach the handler with jQuery:

```
$('body').on('.hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID', 'click', function() {
    FillVoyageCompanyData($(this).data('vacid'))
});
```

Comment: it is working fine but i am using asynchronous posts. if i use          $('#hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID').click(function() {
    FillVoyageCompanyData($(this).data('vacid'))
}); in document.ready then it will work only once. if i add another record it will not be fired for another record.

Comment: You're only allowed one `#hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID` in the document, so you can't add another record, unless it has a different ID.

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID. You can have two elements with the same class, but not two with the same id. See my update

Comment: $('body').on('.hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID', 'click', function() {
    FillVoyageCompanyData($(this).data('vacid'))
});
is not working.. and with $('.hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID').click(function() {
            FillVoyageCompanyData($(".hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID").data('vacid'));
        }); function is called but picked parameters of uppermost record... :(

Comment: In what sense does the first not work? The second one should work if you replace `$(".hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID")` with `$(this)`

Comment: thanks a lot!!! but only 1 problem remained.. as i have told i am using ajax posts.. after clicking on this link edit popup displays.. once i click on save button on edit popup..           "hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID" is not click-able after that..  and $('body').on('.hlnkEditVoyageAssosiatedCompanyID', 'click', function() { FillVoyageCompanyData($(this).data('vacid')) }); is not working.. it is not allowed to click even once. please help me out!!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: ../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js